# Executing script to modify tab html from service worker

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to intercept a GET request using a service worker and print the GET request's output onto the current page, however I can't execute any Javascript on the page...

Here's the extension code I've used (Generalized to work on all URLs)

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "name": "Getting Started Example",
  "description": "Build an Extension!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "<all_urls>",
    "activeTab",
    "*://*/*",
    "tabs"
  ],
  
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

`background.js`

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details)
    {
    chrome.tabs.query(
        { currentWindow: true }, 
        function(tabs) 
        {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, 
            {
                code: 'alert("yo")'
            }, function() { });
        });
     return {cancel: false};
  },
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
);
```

I keep getting the error `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of url "chrome://extensions/". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.` (Even though I allowed permission on all URLs and on the active tab??)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `activeTab` permission as it won't give you access to the `chrome://` pages anyway (these are protected browser UI pages), its purpose is different, more in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab).

No need for `chrome.tabs.query` either. You probably want to run the code in the tab that made the request in which case just use `details.tabId`, see more info in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest).

No need for `service_worker` as it won't wake up for webRequest events, which is a [known bug](https://crbug.com/1024211) in Chrome. Just use the standard ManifestV2 `scripts`.

```json
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
```

Also you may want to limit the `types` of requests to just xhr:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(details => {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId, {
    frameId: details.frameId,
    code: 'console.log(' + JSON.stringify(details) + ')',
  }, () => chrome.runtime.lastError); // suppressing errors
}, {
  urls: ['<all_urls>'],
  types: ['xmlhttprequest'],
});
```

Comment: I understand the redundancy for `activeTab` and `chrome.tabs.query`, but how come your `chrome.tabs.executeScript` is different than mine? (and why does that change allow it to run?) The suppressing errors callback?

Comment: The difference is tabId. I think the second paragraph explains it.